# QBSDK Can not connect in debug environment

Tags: vb.net, qbfc

I have a proven application that uses qbsdk 13. This was working in mid June. I am picking it up again after an interruption.

Verion Information

QB Enterprise Solutions Accountant 16.0 installed on my dev machine
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015  Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
I am running win10

My primary symptom is that the call to SessionManager.BeginSession never comes back. (As I type this, the call has been pending for 30 minutes)

Some additional symptoms are

- If I delete the 3rd Party App permissions, I do not get re prompted for them.
- If I include a filename in openConnection, I often (not always) get an error about trying to open a connection w/ 2 instances of QB running.

Here are some things I have done to debug the problem

I have tried two different QB files
I have verified that "qbXML Test +" works for the QB File(s) I am accessing
I have deleted the 3rd Party App permissions and let QB request them again
I verified that all the projects in my solution are built as x86
I uninstalled qbsdk13 and reinstalled it.

The fact that qbXMLTest works and my project doesn't, tells me that uninstalling quickbooks and the sdk wont really help. I reinstalled qbsdk13 because I ran out of useful ideas.

On a hunch, I built a simple app that connects and does a simple query. 
I recreated the issue, Visual studio debugger never returns from the call to SessionManager.BeginSession. 
**HOWEVER, running the .EXE performs like a champ** and displays the result of my query.

I verified the .EXE works regardless of running as administrator or not. 
I have tried running visual studio as administrator. That does not help.

It is my theory that Visual Studio is not even communicating with QB. This is supported by the fact that I never get prompted for Permissions.

Since June (the last time this worked), I know that Intuit rolled out some security enhancements. Possibly somehow that is preventing it from working with the debugger?

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? 
Are there any work arounds, or additional trouble shooting steps I can take?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Disable Quick Start by going to *edit->preferences->'General'* and under the 'My Preferences' - disable / un-check the option "Keep Quickbooks running for quick startups".
2. Close QB and wait for the QBW32.exe process to get out of your process list.
3. Make sure that your 'UAC' {User Access Control' levels are set to low, if possible or run the QB in elevated mode (Run as Administrator).
4. Open a command window (Administrator mode {run as Admin})and there is a reboot.bat file in the QB installed location: (C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2016 Enterprise Accountant 16.0). Run the batch file Reboot.bat.
5. Now Open QB and keep the company file opened.
6. Remove your app, if it is already listed under *'Edit->Preferences->Integrated Applications'* under the 'Company Preferences' and remove your app.
7. Try running your app again (Run as Administrator) and see whether the SDK Authorization dialog gets popped-up.